# To get tha auto increment id of first table as the foreign id of another table at a same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have created two different tables for the one form. The upper part of form is inserted into one table and below part of form is inserted into another table.
I have to take the **Primary Id** of first table as the **Foreign Id** for Another table.

Is it possible? and is so then how?
Here is the query code of php

```
    if(isset($_POST['add_hostel']))
{
    extract($_POST);
    $checkbox = implode(',',$_POST['checkbox']);
    $checkbox1 = implode(',',$_POST['checkbox1']);
    $insert_details = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `add_hostel` (owner_id,accomodation_type,hostel_for,hostel_name,owner_name,email_id,contact_number,alternate_number,address,city,website) VALUES 
                                ('".$_SESSION['login_id']."','".$checkbox."','".$checkbox1."','".$hostel_name."','".$ownername."','".$email."','".$contact_no."','".$phonealternate."','".$address."','".$searchTextField."','".$hostel_website."')") or die(mysql_error());        
}

if(isset($_POST['add_hostel']))
{   
    extract($_POST);
    $hostel_id = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");

    $checkbox2 = implode(',',$_POST['checkbox2']);
    $checkbox3 = implode(',',$_POST['checkbox3']);

    $insert_details1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `hostel_features` (hostel_id,facilities_info,food_type,breakfast,lunch,dinner,special) VALUES 
                                ('".$hostel_id."','".$checkbox2."','".$checkbox3."','".$breakfast."','".$lunch."','".$dinner."','".$special."')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The php mysql extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0

Instead use [the mysqli extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) which allows you to access the functionality provided by MySQL 4.1 and above.

You can solve your problem with [insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

```
$hostel_id = $mysqli->insert_id; // or  mysqli_insert_id() for procedural style
```

*If for some reason you want to stick with mysql the procedural way is almost the same:*

```
$hostel_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: Ok thanks i got it these answer earlier only. But thanks for ur support.